# Prove the inequality $\sum_{i,j = 1}^n {{A_{i,j}}({x_i}^2 - {x_i}{x_j})} \ge 0 $

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, inequality, inner-products, sums-of-squares

A is a square matrix with positive elements and x is a real vector (both of them n>1 dimensional). Prove that for any such matrix and vector
$$\sum\limits_{i,j = 1}^n {{A_{i,j}}({x_i}^2 - {x_i}{x_j})}  \ge 0 $$
P.S.#1: I am not 100% sure that the inequality holds but I have seen it happen in numerous numerical examples (for random matrices and vectors),
P.S.#2: I need this to prove the uniqueness of the solution to a PDE.

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric? If so, I think a diagonal dominance argument can be used to show the above inequality is true.

Comment: @copper.hat Unfortunately the only feature of A is that all of its elements are non-negative